# SharePoint Rest API - Get exact dates as being shown in SharePoint list irrespective of current user's timezone

Tags: office-365, 2016, sharepoint-rest-api, date

I have a SharePoint list with custom forms, where the items are created from users in various timezones.

The dates are getting saved correctly in the SharePoint list, but when the item is viewed from people in other timezones, the dates are getting changed as per their timezone.

For example, 24 Feb 2020 is shown as 23 Feb 2020 as the date string has value 2020-02-20T23:00:00Z. So when I use

```
moment(item.StartDate).format("DD/MM/YYYY")
```

it is shown as `23/02/2020`
 . But in the SharePoint list view, it is displayed correctly as 24 Feb 2020. Is there a way to show the dates like how it is shown in the SharePoint view? and not based on current users timezone

Answer (score 1):

I used moment js timezones to convert the date to the timezone that is used in the SharePoint site. To do this, go to the regional settings `(http://site/_layouts/15/regionalsetng.aspx)` and notice the timezone. 
Then in your code, add that timezone to your moment js

```
https://github.com/moment/moment-timezone/blob/develop/data/packed/latest.json
```

For example, if its Brussels, add

```
moment.tz.add(["Europe/Brussels|WET CET CEST WEST|0 -10 -20 -10|0121212103030303030303030303030303030303030303030303212121212121212121212121212121212121212121212121212121212121212121212121212121212121212121212121212121212121212121212121212121212121|-2ehc0 3zX0 11c0 1iO0 11A0 1o00 11A0 my0 Ic0 1qM0 Rc0 1EM0 UM0 1u00 10o0 1io0 1io0 17c0 1a00 1fA0 1cM0 1cM0 1io0 17c0 1fA0 1a00 1io0 1a30 1io0 17c0 1fA0 1a00 1io0 17c0 1cM0 1cM0 1a00 1io0 1cM0 1cM0 1a00 1fA0 1io0 17c0 1cM0 1cM0 1a00 1fA0 1io0 1qM0 Dc0 y00 5Wn0 WM0 1fA0 1cM0 16M0 1iM0 16M0 1C00 Uo0 1eeo0 1a00 1fA0 1cM0 1cM0 1cM0 1fA0 1a00 1cM0 1cM0 1cM0 1cM0 1cM0 1cM0 1cM0 1fA0 1cM0 1cM0 1cM0 1cM0 1cM0 1cM0 1cM0 1cM0 1cM0 1cM0 1cM0 1fA0 1cM0 1cM0 1cM0 1cM0 1cM0 1cM0 1cM0 1cM0 1cM0 1cM0 1fA0 1o00 11A0 1o00 11A0 1o00 11A0 1qM0 WM0 1qM0 WM0 1qM0 11A0 1o00 11A0 1o00 11A0 1qM0 WM0 1qM0 WM0 1qM0 WM0 1qM0 11A0 1o00 11A0 1o00 11A0 1qM0 WM0 1qM0 WM0 1qM0 11A0 1o00 11A0 1o00 11A0 1o00 11A0 1qM0 WM0 1qM0 WM0 1qM0 11A0 1o00 11A0 1o00 11A0 1qM0 WM0 1qM0 WM0 1qM0 11A0 1o00 11A0 1o00 11A0 1o00 11A0 1qM0 WM0 1qM0 WM0 1qM0 11A0 1o00 11A0 1o00 11A0 1qM0 WM0 1qM0 WM0 1qM0 WM0 1qM0 11A0 1o00 11A0 1o00|21e5"]);
```

Then, convert the date to Brussels timezone using the below code

```
moment(data.d.StartDate).tz("Europe/Brussels").format("DD/MM/YYYY");
```